# How to keep banner in list page with respective to the selected category?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I magento 1.9.2.4 , I want to add banner in the product list page randomly with respect to the selected category.Someone kindly guide me in getting this done.

Comment: you can do this by adding static block to each category

Comment: you need slider or only image

Comment: I need to keep only image

Answer (score 0):

Answer Found.

Have to add the image in a new static block using image tag like:

```
 <img  src="{{media url="wysiwyg/banner.jpg"}}" alt="">
```

Then We have to choose the category for which we wish to display the banner image from `catalog/manage categories` .

switch to `display settings` tab.

Select `static Block and Products` from `display mode` option.

Finally select the `static block` created with the banner from `CMS Block` option and save.

Now If you refresh the category page, the banner image will be displayed there.